# Continuous TypeError when attempting to add integers in a list?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

Okay. I feel a bit silly for having so much trouble with this problem, but essentially, here's the code I have so far:

```
def addition_nest(x):
    netsum = 0
    sublist = []
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for sublist in x:
            if sublist == []:
                return netsum
            else:
                netsum = netsum + addition_nest(sublist)
        return netsum
```

I keep getting an error saying the operand + does not work with int and NoneTypes. Any ideas on how I can bypass this? The code basically needs to be able to add up all the integers in a list/nested list, and omit any other elements within the list.

Comment: Your code seems to work okay, if you indent that `netsum = 0` line. What kind of input gives you that problem?

Comment: Without actually running the code, I am pretty sure that error is coming from the line: `netsum = netsum + addition_nest(..)` (attempting to add integer(netsum) and a possible NoneType (return value of the recursive call). Now to figure out where your function could possibly return a None, you should trace out all return points. In your code, the last line is an implicit `return None`. So, are you passing any nested element that is neither an int or list? If so, the last line should just say: `return 0`.

Comment: Have you considered what will happen if `x` is neither an `int` nor a `list`?

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you the expected output.

```
def addition_nest(x):
    netsum = 0
    if isinstance(x, int):
    # if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        for each_element in x:
            if isinstance(each_element, int):
            # if isinstance(each_element, (int, float)):
                netsum += each_element
            elif isinstance(each_element, list):
                netsum += addition_nest(each_element)
        return netsum

print(addition_nest(25))  ## Output: 25
print(addition_nest([25, 30, 'a']))  ## Output: 55
print(addition_nest([25, 30, ['a', 10, 20]]))  ## Output: 85
```

If you want the above code to work with `float` also, replace the if conditions with the commented lines.

In your existing code, you have handled the scenarios for when an element inside the parent list is another list or an integer. But you didn't handle it for other data types. That is the reason for the error you are facing.

Comment: Why the strange use of `replace()` and `isdigit()` instead of simply `isinstance(x, (int, float))`

Comment: You also need to replace the other type test, `if isinstance(x, int):`, otherwise `addition_nest(25.4)` doesn't work.

Comment: This code does an *implcit* return with `addition_nest('a')` instead of an *explicit* one.  Two explicit returns and one implicit one doesn't seem like good code style.

Comment: I have another issue with the code as is: If you visualize the recursion tree, the *step* to check `isinstance(x, int)` (or that of `list`) happens at both depth L and L+1. They can always be unified. Here's a simplified version: https://ideone.com/XWuQ28

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the third line is not used and pointless

```
sublist = []
```

Second, in cases that it is a list just simply call the function on every element and add together.

```
def addition_nest(x):
    netsum = 0
    sublist = []
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x
    if isinstance(x, list):
        for sublist in x:
            netsum = netsum + addition_nest(sublist)
        return netsum
```

This will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simpler than you and other answers are making it.  First rule of recursion is let the recursion do the work:

```
def addition_nest(unknown):
    if isinstance(unknown, list):
        if unknown:  # not empty
            head, *tail = unknown
            return addition_nest(head) + addition_nest(tail)

        return 0  # empty

    if isinstance(unknown, (int, float)):
        return unknown

    return 0  # neither list nor number
```

OTOH, if we want to reduce recursion and increase efficiency, we could move in the direction of something like:

```
def addition_nest(unknown):
    if isinstance(unknown, (int, float)):
        return unknown

    if isinstance(unknown, list):
        return sum(map(addition_nest, unknown))

    return 0
```

Which is still *recursion*, though *indirectly* as we don't *directly* call the function from itself but rather hand it off to `map()`.

Comment: -1: IMO avoid loops is probably not a great advice. I wouldn't turn a simple iteration (for instance over a list) into a needless recursion -- it sacrifices readability, simplicity, and likely performance for almost nothing in return.

Comment: @UltraInstinct, I've removed the offending second rule and noted in my edit comment that it is essentially opinionated, as is your objection to it.  I view this as an *exercise in recursion* so why not use only recursion to solve it?  I personally find it as readable as the other answers which mix recursion and iteration but are flawed: mixing implicit and explicit returns; unused variables.  I hope I've satisfied your objection!

Comment: Reversed the -1 :). As far as the other answers go, I don't agree with any of them either. Here's my version of the answer (hoping OP sees it): https://ideone.com/XWuQ28